# IGeometryBridge.GetPoints throws NotImplementedException. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, .net

I am working on some .NET code that processes lots of polygon geometries at the vertex level. In order to [reduce COM interop overhead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647714.aspx), I want to call [`IGeometryBridge2.GetPoints`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetPoints_Method/002m000001t4000000/) once instead of calling [`IPointCollection.Point`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Point_Property/002m00000286000000/) repeatedly:

```
// using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
static IPoint[] GetVertices(this IPolygon singlepartPolygon)
{
    var pointCollection = (IPointCollection4)singlepartPolygon;
    var points = new IPoint[pointCollection.PointCount];
    var geometryBridge = (IGeometryBridge2)new GeometryEnvironment();
    geometryBridge.GetPoints(pointCollection, 0, ref points);
    return points;
}
```

`geometryBridge.GetPoints(…)` throws a `NotImplementedException`.

(I have tried initialising the `points` array with empty `Point` instances before calling `GetPoints`, but this didn't make any difference. I tried `geometryBridge.QueryPoints(…)`, too, and this failed with a different exception.)

Am I doing something wrong, or is this more likely to be a bug?

Comment: The doc implies it only works for multipoint, which kinda defeats the purpose of interface based programming. Maybe a leaky abstraction?

Comment: Did you try QueryGeometries?

Comment: I have found the best way to reduce COM interop overhead during vertex-heavy operations is to use the WKS structure related methods, like QueryWKSPoints, SetWKSPoints, InsertWKSPoints etc. Depends on your scenario, but the performance gain should be greater.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but try `GeometryEnvironmentClass()` instead of `GeometryEnvironment()`. That is the .NET runtime callable wrapper (RCW) for the GeometryEnvironment COM type: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000151000000

Comment: @blah238: I've tried this, with no difference.

Comment: `new GeometryEnvironment()` is exactly the same as `new GeometryEnvironmentClass()`. `GeometryEnvironment` (which is an interface) is decorated with the CoClass attribute: `CoClass(typeof(GeometryEnvironmentClass))`, so that the compiler knows which class you are instantating. This is how the .NET COM type library importer converts types (for better compatibility with legacy languages and environments).

Comment: Ah, so ESRI didn't just make up that scheme? Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IGeometryBridge.QueryPoints()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001tp000000) works for me at ArcGIS 10.1 SP1:

```
static IPoint[] GetVertices2(this IPolygon singlepartPolygon)
{
    var pointCollection = (IPointCollection4)singlepartPolygon;
    var points = new IPoint[pointCollection.PointCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new PointClass();
    }
    var geometryBridge = (IGeometryBridge)new GeometryEnvironmentClass();
    geometryBridge.QueryPoints(pointCollection, 0, ref points);
    return points;
}
```

Comment: This could be due to SP1. Does it also work without the `for` loop, i.e. if you don't initialise the array?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, but the array elements are all null.

Comment: I used [LINQPad](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32297/753) to test this, BTW, here is my query: https://gist.github.com/4702432. Tested against both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: This answer talks about `QueryPoints`. Does this mean that `GetPoints` also didn't work for you? (Or did your Gist code which uses `GetPoints` work?)

Comment: Correct, as Kirk mentioned it is not implemented for anything but Multipoint geometries.

Comment: The Gist includes both methods (QueryPoints and GetPoints) so you can test them.